# Heap corruption detected when deleting char*

Tags: c++

I am tring to copy a const char* to a char* and below is what I have written:

```
int main()
{
    const char* string = "Hello";
    int size = strlen(string) + 1; // add '/0' in the end
    char* data = new char(size);
    memcpy(data, string, size);
    delete data;
}
```

unfortunately I am getting a error with "Heap corruption detected: after normal block (#77)".
I have no idea what the problem is.

I am complying my code using MSVC under visual studio 2019.

Comment: You are allocating only a single `char`, not an array. Use `new char [size]` and later respectively `delete[] data;`

Comment: thanks for the answer. You are totally right.

Answer (score 2):

`new char(size)` is not allocating an array of characters but allocating single character whose value is `size`.

You should use `new char[size]` to allocate an array and `delete[] data;` to delete the array.